# Using vars for specific urls in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, variables

I'm editing htaccess for the first time and don't know how to write proper urls redirectings.
I googled that problem, but there are just no answers for redirecting, only rewriting.

I have links like /?post=89 on my site and I wanted to redirect them to /stranica/89/

Could you possibly help me, how to use vars to catch that number and redirect correctly?

Tried suggested solution, didn't work. I'm seeking for something like this

Redirect index.php/?post=$ /stranica/$1/

but that code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different querystring patterns in your site, you can try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*).php /$1/%1/%2/? [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect urls like /index.php?id=5 to /index/id/5/

The below code will redirect the exact url which you mentioned on your question

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post=(.*)
    RewriteRule ^index.php /index/stranica/%1/? [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's not working :( I added 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post=(.*)
RewriteRule ^index.php /index/stranica/%1/? [R,L] 

to the end of my htaccess file, nothing happened. I don't know, maybe I need to use something like this 

Redirect index.php/?post=$ /stranica/$1/

Comment: Check your Apache configuration file and make sure AllowOverride Directive is configured to allow .htaccess file and make sure your sever has mod_rewrite installed and active.